# How to display all legends when plotting using *args & seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

My data & code are as below

```
w = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
vals = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,4,6,8,8,8,8,8,7,1],[1,4,2,4,8,9,8,8,7,2]]

def plot_compare(*id_nums):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    leg=[]
    for id_num in id_nums:
        rel = vals[id_num]
        sns.lineplot(x=w, y=rel)
        leg.append(id_num)
    fig.legend(labels=[leg],loc=5,);
plot_compare(0,2)
```

The idea was to get multiple line plots with just one function (I my actual data I have a lot of values that need to be plotted)
When I run the code as above, I get the plot as below.
Line plots are exactly as I want, but the legend is just one item instead of 2 items (since I have plotted 2 line graphs).
I have tried moving the legend line inside of the for loop but no use. I want a may legends as the line plots.
Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having legend as list of list. Instead use `fig.legend(labels=leg,loc=5)`

Use:

```
w = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
vals = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,4,6,8,8,8,8,8,7,1],[1,4,2,4,8,9,8,8,7,2]]

def plot_compare(*id_nums):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    leg=[]
    for id_num in id_nums:
        rel = vals[id_num]
        sns.lineplot(x=w, y=rel)
        leg.append(id_num)
    fig.legend(labels=leg,loc=5)
    plt.show()
plot_compare(0,2)
```

[image]